# Excel: Conditional Format Table Row dependant on dates in multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I would like to set up conditional formatting to prioritize and highlight table row dependent on if a date is entered in cell

i.e.
Highlight row  if any date entered into row K, 
Highlight row  if any date entered into row L, 
Highlight row  if any date entered into row M,

The second part is that I would like the highlighting to have a priority so  date in row L takes precedence over date in row K, and a date in row M would take precedence over date in row L or K

Right now I do this manually - but I'm sure there is a way to automate.  Here is a screen shot of what I want

[priority conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMBxx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create three rules exactly the same but with the different formatting.

I used the formula of `=$K1<>""` for the first rule and `=$1:$100` in the Applies to column. (Set to red)
Then created the next with formula `=$L1<>""` with the same 'Applies to' (set to blue)
Then again for `=$M1<>""` (set to green)

You should change the 1 in both *Rule formula* and *Applies to*, to the first row you want to apply formatting on, and the 100 to the last row to suit your needs.

Put the highest priority at the top (so if you want a date in M to take precedence over L, and L over K, put them in that order)

[image]

One other tip is whenever you go to edit these rules, *change the **Show Formatting rules for** from **Current Selection** to **This Worksheet*** to see all the rules properly. (Otherwise you can unknowingly create more rules, or can't find existing rules)

Also note it also changes some of the rules, so when doing this you may need to go back and re-fix certain values. (I think if you update the *applies to* range it sometimes changes the Formula from 1 to 1048561 and you have to fix it back to 1 again) (1 being the first row to apply this formatting)

I found the advice on [this site](https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-rows-based-on-cell-value/) helpful to get formatting to apply to a whole row.